# How to force a layout responsive to just one page

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to force my layout shows the elements responsive in all kind of smartphones. I'm working on Android Studio 3.5

I want my app see like this in all devices (layout just in one view)
[image]

But in some devices with a smaller screen my same layout looks like this:

[image]

How to force my layout and all my elements to see in one page like my first image and avoid to? I don't want any kind of scrollview, I just one all my elements in one view.

My layout.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Fragments.InicioFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity=""
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ScrollView
            android:background="@drawable/border_black_radius"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contenido_seccion1"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/prueba"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_m"/>
            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/temas_recycler"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/resumen_recycler"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout)

Constraint layout works with screen ratios and (almost) always will represent your layout in the same way.

Also try to use DPs whenever you can and try to create a dimens.xml resource for each screen density.

Check this too: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: I'm working on that but i don't see differences, do you have more examples about how to use widths and heights responsives on the Constraint Layout?

Comment: Thats why I say (always). It's almost impossible to make your layout exactly in every device with just constraints. Check the other link I mention and try to play with different dimensions in every density. There are also some libraries like https://github.com/MrNouri/DynamicSizes that try to make different dimensions for different screen densities but it's not 100% accurate.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a glance on that.